# how to pass data from one screen to another screen using Segue

Tags: iphone

I have 2 views A and B. View A contains a table of 1 section with 2 rows. Each row has each own picture....My task is how to display in view B a picture of row 1 when you click on row one. If you click on row 2, view B will display picture of row 2. Please show me the way to pass data from one to another view using seque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have controllers ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB for the two views and also assuming that you have created a segue between the views in storyboard with an identifier

ViewControllerA should implement this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (segue.identifier.length > 0)
    {        
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"your_identifier_name"])
        {
            ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
            //And you can pass data between the two controller.  
            viewControllerB.currentRow = self.selectedRow; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just given it a try. Everything is fine but when I clicked on each row, view B cant be shown, I am still at view A. Have I missed something..

Comment: guess your segue is not established. So for doing that, in ViewControllerA, you would do this in your tableviewdelegate protocol method                                                                    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your_identifier_name sender:self];
}

Answer (score 1):

jajo87's answer will work, but if you're asking, you don't have a full grasp on MVC design. Both ViewControllers should be pulling the images from a single model (a custom subclass of NSObject in a file you create with command-N). That model should have a property that represents the image you picked. Both ViewControllers can have pointers to the model; pass them along when you instantiate ViewController B.